# Karma Error on AngularJS Test

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to understand the grunt-karma plugin and jasmine framework to write first ever karma test. when i run karma test (grunt test ) i'm seeing the error for initialize module, scope. What am i doing wrong ? thanks for your help.

gruntfile.js

```
 karma: {
        unit: {
          configFile: 'karma.conf.js'
        }
      }

grunt.registerTask('test',['karma:unit']);
```

karma.conf.js

```
files: [
  'scripts/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'scripts/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'config/config.js',
  'scripts/app.js',
  'scripts/controllers/*.js',
  'test/unittest/personController.test.js'
],
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['services.config']);
```

personController.js

```
app.controller('personCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    $scope.fullName = function() {
        return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
    };
}]);
```

config.js (service.config)

```
'use strict';

angular.module('services.config', [])
  .constant('configuration', {
    getAllBooks: '@@getAllBooks'
});
```

personController.test.js

```
describe('Testing AngularJS SampleApp [app]', function (){

    //myApp will be loaded once instead of mentioning in every it() function 
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    describe('1.Testing SampleApp Controllers', function(){

        var scope;
        var ctrl;

        //loading controller once inside describe instead of every it() function
        beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$rootScope){
                scope = $rootScope.$new();
                ctrl = $controller('personCtrl',{$scope:scope});
            }));

        afterEach(function(){
            //clean-up code 
        });

        it('should initialize the scope', function(){
            expect(scope.firstName).toBeDefined('John');
            expect(scope.lastName).toBeDefined('Doe');
        });

    });
});
```

ERROR:

```
15 09 2016 17:08:37.568:INFO [Chrome 52.0.2743 (Mac OS X 10.10.5)]: Connected on socket /#Pq9aUWSZ6FSyQjeRAAAA with id 50553444
Chrome 52.0.2743 (Mac OS X 10.10.5) Testing AngularJS SampleApp [app] 1.Testing SampleApp Controllers should initialize the scope FAILED
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module services.config due to:
    Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string
        at scripts/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
```

and

```
at Object.workFn (scripts/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3074:52)
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
        at Object.<anonymous> (test/unittest/personController.test.js:23:16)
Chrome 52.0.2743 (Mac OS X 10.10.5): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.034 secs / 0.02 secs)
```

Questions:
1. What's the best way to refer to karma.con.js from grunt file.js ? I have read in some blogs we can also override all karma.conf.js properties in grunt file instead of referring to the file ?
2. What is the best way to access controller scope in xxx.test.js files ?

Comment: There is an error in  services.config module, the error clearly specifies this. Please, provide source code for  services.config module

Comment: @estus: thanks for your time. I have edited the question with config.js file which defines the service.config. The code works fine and didn't see any errors either. But the testing fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to troubleshoot the problem, thanks estus for pointing out the problem and i should have realized.

personController.test.js

```
beforeEach(module('services.config'));
beforeEach(module('myApp'));
```

I didn't load `services.config` module which is used in `myApp`. and then i got error for TypeError: angular.element.cleanData is not a function. I had to make sure versions of `angular` and `angular-mocks` are the same.

Take Away
1.load all dependent modules before loading the app
2.Add angualr, angualr-mocks, and links to all the script files in order
3.Make sure to install the compatible angular and angular-mocks version